# HTML mail with dyanmic values

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Here is what I need to do.  I need to be able to dynamically generate custom emails.  I have been using PHP's mail() function, but I have been encouraged to try phpmailer or Zendmail.  But it doesn't seem to be able to handle custom emails.

What I need to do is be able to grab values from the form and insert them into the body of the message.  I've been doing:

```
$message = '<html><body><p>First name: ' $first . '<br/><br/>';
$message .= ...(rest of message)
```

Then I do:

`mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);` using the right headers for HTML.

Is there a way to do what I want with phpmailer or Zendmail?  Is there a way to do this in OOP instead that might improve on what are getting to be very lengthy pages?  I'd appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Generally speaking, the way is pretty much the same with Zend_Mailer as it is with mail(): You compose the message, and send it. What part are you having problems with?

Comment: Why can't you do what you want with phpmailer or Zendmail?  Also, the way you are currently sending your mail is incorrect, unless you want the text of that HTML to show up.

Comment: If you use the right headers, the HTML doesn't show.  Just the formatted content.  I can't get the values to show in the HTML mail.  I just get blank spaces where the dynamic values should be inserted.

Comment: There's a problem with your code.  You forgot the concatenation dot (`.`) right before `$first`.  Don't know if that's your actual code, though...

Comment: The missing dot is a typo on my part.  This is an example, not part of my actual code.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using phpmailer you could try the code below.

```
$message = '<html><body><p>First name: '. $first . '<br/><br/>';

$mailer = new PHPMailer();
// other fields / properties
$mailer->Subject = $subject;
$mailer->AddAddress($receipient);
$mailer->IsHTML(true);
$mailer->Body = $message;
$mailer->Send();
```

you'd need to set the other fields for it to work properly though.

Comment: You forgot the `.` before `$first`.

Comment: Scartag, I tried that and it ignores the dynamic values.  Other thoughts?

Comment: @shummel7845: Then your variables are empty.  You need to find out why.

Comment: Doing so, I would also set an alternate body part for those that don't have HTML email.  Something like this should work:

Comment: $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($message)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one of the main points of having a mail library is to be able to create complex emails (more easily).  I would also recommend SwiftMailer.

http://swiftmailer.org